# Can I use Facebook Pixels for Native android app

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

Has anyone familiar with Facebook Pixels, is Facebook pixels for Native Android apps or is it Only for web Sites and web apps

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/ _“The Facebook pixel is a snippet of JavaScript code that allows you to track visitor activity on your website. […] If you want to track User activity in a mobile app, refer to our App Events documentation instead.”_

Answer (score 0):

Facebook pixel only meant for websites.